# Which structure is more useful?

Tags: mysql, structure

I am working on a browser-based online game. I'm using PHP and MySQL. There will be users and user's villages.

## Structure A

```
# users
-------
.id
.username
.password
.email

# villages
----------
.id
.name
.coordinate_x
.coordinate_y
.user_id
```

## Structure B

```
# users
--------
.id
.username
.password
.email

# villages
----------
.id
.name
.coordiante_x
.coordinate_y

# users_villages
----------------
.user_id
.village_id
```

Which structure will be useful ?

(Note: Sorry, I couldn't find more explanatory title for the question)

### Correction:

I should have been clearer. Each user can own many villages, and a village belongs to only one user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Structure A is good if there is only one user per village.  It allows a one-to-many relationship.  One or more villages can be associated with a given user.

If there can be many villages per user then structure B is needed for the many-to-many relationship.  Each user can have (own or live in?) one or more villages and each village can be associated with one or more users.

Answer (score 2):

That totally depends on what you want to achieve. If you want each village to belong to a single user, the first is better. If you want villages to be owned/inhabited/whatever by more than one user *and* each user be able to own multiple villages, the second is better.

Answer (score 1):

Structure B is going to be a more flexible solution. It is normalised to a higher form (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and will support any relationship Structure A supports plus more.